# Copy git submodules from one repo to another

Tags: git, git-submodules

I'm developing a set of libraries that depend on a common set of other libraries.

I'd like to copy the .gitsubmodules file from one repo that has all of the necessary submodules into all of the other repos.

However I can't seem to get git to recognize the submodules file, or otherwise do anything to pull the submodules into the new repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git needs two things to realize a submodule:

1. the configuration from the `.gitmodules` file, and
2. a corresponding `commit` entry in the index...which you get by running `git submodule add`.

This is explicit [in the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule), which says this about the `git submodule init` command:

> Initialize the submodules recorded in the index (which were added and committed elsewhere) by setting `submodule.$name.url` in `.git/config`. It uses the same setting from `.gitmodules` as a template....

Practically, this means you'll need to run `git submodule add` for each submodule. If you do this often, you could write a script that would read the submodule configuration from the `.gitmodules` file and run the appropriate `git submodule add` commands. Maybe something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

submodules=( $(git config -f .gitmodules --name-only --get-regexp 'submodule\..*\.path' | cut -f2 -d.) )
for name in "${submodules[@]}"; do
    path="$(git config -f .gitmodules --get submodule."$name".path)"
    url="$(git config -f .gitmodules --get submodule."$name".url)"

    git submodule add "$url" "$path"
done
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for the detailed script. I had already created a script to manually add all of the dependencies. Was just hoping to re-use the .gitmodule file as is, since the script ended up creating a new one anyway.